# Ipv6 Individual ip adresses

Tags: internet, ipv6, isp

my question is when you use ipv6, does the router still use NAT?
I've searched for an hour and haven't found any info on this.

what i mean is whether the ISP will use the same ip for multiple homes, use one ip per home, and then the router splits it, or whether the router gives individual public ip's to each device.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6's address space is intentionally large enough so that you *don't* need NAT. That's not to say that you can't "roll your own" through aggressive proxy configurations and very strict firewall rules. Strictly speaking, there is no NAT.

That said, though, home routers basically block all external traffic unless it's expressly permitted (i.e., everything is guilty until proven innocent.)